# Rails 3 / jquery / ajax - can i change this to submit one answer instead of the entire form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm grateful to the folks who helped me meander my way through a diagnostic process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192060/jquery-return-false-works-in-version-1-6-but-not-1-6-1-rails-3). I rewrote the code that i am hoping will continue to work through future versions of jQuery.

I am concerned, though, about two things:

1. Have i coded something else that is going to come back and bite me in the tail?
2. Quite a few clients complete part of
   the questions, close the browser and
   expect their work to be there when
   they came back to finish. So the entire form is
   submitted every time a radio button
   is clicked (100+ records). I wondered
   about the possibility of creating a
   form for each question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929602/can-you-render-a-page-with-multiple-forms-instead-of-one-form-for-a-jquery-rails) and
   received no responses. Is there some
   way to submit one answer at a time
   instead of the whole form?

view:

```
    <%= form_tag update_result_answers_path, :remote => true do %>
    <% @answers.each do |q| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= q[0].question %></td>
            <% [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].each do |f| %>
                <% if f == q[1].score
                    chk="checked='checked'"
                else
                    chk=""
                end %>
                <td>
                    <input "<%= chk %>" class="submittable" name="answer[<%=q[1].id%>]" type="radio" value="<%= f %>" />
                </td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

application.js:

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
        return false;
        }
    );
```

controller:

```
  def update_result
    params[:answer].each_pair do |key,value|
      @ans = Answer.find(key.to_i)
      @ans.update_attributes(:score => value)
    end
  end
```

_index.js.erb:

```
$("#answers").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(@answers)) %>");
```

Thank you!

Comment: I made a gem which could help you with your second issue. It allows your users to close the browser and get back their form when they come back. The link is here : https://github.com/MrRuru/rails_form_autosave.

Comment: @MrRuru, i read through the documentation. If you come to the point where you think the gem is production ready, i would like to use it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the only thing left for it to be production ready is some user returns. The test suite is done and running, and I cannot produce any bugs manually. If advise you to test it if you'd like, and I'd be really glad to know if it is working for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep your view as it is, and change the application.js, to be as little obtrusive as possible :

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
  $.post(
    $(this).closest('form').attr('href'),
    $(this).serialize()
  );
});
```

EDIT : I didn't see that you want to render the answers afterwards. I'm not sure how to avoid code duplication with this solution then...

Comment: thanks for your help. I am getting this error: "Started POST "/undefined" for 127.0.0.1 at... ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/undefined"): Also, the answers don't need to be rendered again. I don't know where you are getting that indication. Can you tell me? Thanks again.